# ListResultsConsumer: Duplicate row was found and `ASSERT` was specified

Tags: hibernate, jpa

- JDK 17
- JPA 3.1
- Hibernate 6.2

After upgrading spring boot 2.x to 3.x which involves upgrading from hibernate 5.x to 6.x I get this error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Duplicate row was found and `ASSERT` was specified
```

### Reproducible example

(`MyEntity` below is called `Question` in the example)

https://github.com/RobertHeim/so-duplicate-row

### Background

I have this test running fine, but the last line throws an exception:

```
Language lang = langRepository.findOneByLocale(locale).orElse(null);
final var id = new MyEntityI18nId(
        em.getReference(MyEntity.class, id),
        lang
);
var byIds = myRepo.findAllById(Set.of(id));
assertThat(byIds).hasSize(1);
// fine until here

myRepo.findById(id); // throws org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Duplicate row was found and `ASSERT` was specified
```

I don't understand what that exception means. It first felt like a bug, because I thought it tells me that there is a duplicate in the DB when trying to run `findById(id)`, but I proofed that there is no duplicate row just before the statement. Also there is a unique constraint on the DB that guarantees it, so somehow that cannot be true.

Now I am wondering, what that message actually means.

I tried to create a minimal reproducible example and it turns out that the error goes away when I remove data from a different table. From there I was able to understand that this related data is eagerly fetched and itself also eagerly fetches the `MyEntity` (see `QuestionI18n.QuestionI18nId.question` in the example). Do I understand correctly, that the error wants to tell me that I now end up with the same row in the result set (not in the DB)? or what is it trying to tell me?

### Edit

So by further debugging I found `ListResultsConsumer` and its definition of the enum `UniqueSemantic` that defines `ASSERT` commented with:

> Apply in-memory duplication checks, throwing a HibernateException when duplicates are found

It has been introduced in hibernate 6.x which explains why I did not happen to see the error on 5.x. It also gives me more confidence that I am correct with my understanding of the error message - hibernate tries to inform me that during my query the loadgraph wants to query an entity twice. But is it an severe error or just a hint? Because I would expect hibernate to optimize the query anyway to not really load it twice. Anyway, I am not very confident what the appropriate fix is.

And I still don't really understand why this error happens for `findById` but not for `findByIds` which - to my understanding - should behave exactly the same for the same input ids.

Comment: I have the same bug tried hibernate 6.2.13-FINAL and it's still not working !

Comment: @YoussefNAIT check your load graphs, you probably need to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Little late for this post, but I hope it helps others, that ran into a similar problem.

The exception is thrown when Hibernate maps the result of its generated SQL query into entities and has multiple indistinguishable entities, while expecting a single one.

**Why does entityManager.findByIds() fix it?**

Generated SQL of Robert's reproducing `entityManager.findById(id)`:

```
select 
q1_0.language_id,l1_0.id,l1_0.locale,q1_0.question_id,q2_0.id,c1_0.id,c1_0.yype,o1_0.config_id,o1_0.id,q1_0.text 
from question_i18n q1_0 
left join language l1_0 on l1_0.id=q1_0.language_id 
left join question q2_0 on q2_0.id=q1_0.question_id 
left join question_config c1_0 on q2_0.id=c1_0.id 
left join mc_option o1_0 on c1_0.id=o1_0.config_id 
where (q1_0.language_id,q1_0.question_id) in ((?,?))
```

returns 2 rows, because there are 2 `Options`.

Generated SQL of `entityManager.findByIds(...)`:

```
select q1_0.language_id, q1_0.question_id,q1_0.text 
from question_i18n q1_0 
where(q1_0.language_id,q1_0.question_id) in ((?,?))

select l1_0.id, l1_0.locale 
from language l1_0 
where l1_0.id=?

select q1_0.id, c1_0.id, c1_0.type, o1_0.config_id, o1_0.id 
from question q1_0 
left join question_config c1_0  on q1_0.id=c1_0.id 
left join mc_option o1_0  on c1_0.id=o1_0.config_id 
where q1_0.id=?
```

**Why does entityManager.findById(id) generate a single query?**

QuestionI18n.QuestionI18nId is used as `@EmbeddedId`, has no own ID itself, but foreign ids. That could bend Hibernate to what is possible. I understand, that you want to keep these FKs to have an efficient mapping. In this case JPA wiki recommends using the basic values: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Embedded_Id

I ran into this very same exception when using an broken unidirectional `@OneToMany` without having the foreign ID in the "toMany" class. When querying by ID, Hibernate expected one, but the DB had multiple.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem where I was getting the same error, and since there are no answers here, I'll add my solution in the hopes that it can point you in the right direction.

In my case, the error was being thrown already on the `findAll(Pageable pageable)` method, and as you might notice I was using pagination. My error was only being thrown for certain `Pageable`s, so sometimes the method ran fine and other times it threw the error.

The problem in my case was on `MyEntity`. I had the following code set up:

```
@Entity
@Table("MyEntity")
public class MyEntity {
  ...

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  private MyOtherEntity otherEntity;
}
```

The problem with this was that the connection to MyOtherEntity was actually supposed to be `@OneToMany`. Since `@OneToOne` is eager-loaded by default (as is `@OneToMany`), this meant that when I did `myEntityRepo.findAll(pageable)`, this would throw an error if any of the `MyEntity` contained 2 or more `MyOtherEntity`. As long as all `MyEntity` on the page contained 1 or fewer `MyOtherEntity`, the exception wasn't getting thrown.

So, the solution in my case was to change it to the following:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //LAZY fetch type for good measure, not necessary
@JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private List<MyOtherEntity> otherEntities;
```